# Почему не инкрементируются значения?

Tags: java

Как я понял, создается 4 нити, и каждая из них должна увеличивать на 1 каждый элемент массива values. Но этого не происходит. Почему? Какую роль выполняет мьютекс this в синхронизации в данной задаче?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter1 = new Counter();

        Counter counter2 = new Counter();
        Counter counter3 = new Counter();
        Counter counter4 = new Counter();

        counter1.start();
        counter2.start();
        counter3.start();
        counter4.start();


        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("значение " + i + "= " + values[i]);
//            if (values[i] != 1) {
//                System.out.println("Массив values содержит элементы неравные 1");
//                break;
//            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer count = 0;
    public static int[] values = new int[105];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 105; i++) {
            values[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public static class Counter extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                synchronized (this) {
                    incrementCount();
                    values[getCount()]++;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } while (getCount() < 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А откуда уверенность в том, что потоки не меняют значения массива?

Comment: в методе run это прописано

Comment: Вы пишете, но это не происходит. Почему вы решили, что это не происходит?

Comment: если добавить к какому нибудь потоку join() - то инкрементирование будет

Comment: Конечно, потому что потоки не успевают отработать. Поэтому я и спрашиваю, почему вы уверены, что они не меняют значения? Они меняют, но позже того, как вы проверяете

Comment: если сделать ожидание завершение каждой нити, почему значения в массиве равны 1 а не 4? - ведь каждая нить увеличивает значение на 1

Comment: Вы нигде не обнуляете count. Он всё время растет. А так как все потоки работают с одной и той же переменной, то вы каждый раз берете новое значение массива, а не инкрементируете старое

Comment: но ведь count не объявлена как volatile - значит каждый поток имеет собственную копию этой переменной?

Comment: Вы не до конца понимаете принцип работы модификатора volatile. Что с volatile, что без него переменная count будет в единственном экземпляре и будет общей среди других потоков. Если хотите, чтобы в каждом потоке были свои собственные переменные, рекомендую обратить внимание на ThreadLocal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не успевают значения инкрементиться. Главный поток запускает 4 counter-а и сразу начинает выводить значения values, не дожидаясь завершения counter-ов. Если перед выводом написать:

```
counter1.join()
counter2.join()
counter3.join()
counter4.join()
```

, то в результате появятся числа.

Мютекс this означает, что во время выполнения инкремента счетчиков никто не сможет обратитья к данному экзепляру класса Counter. В данном коде synchronized (this) не делает ничего полезного.

Также в данном коде есть проблемы с одновременным доступом к counter и values из нескольких потоков.

В итоге рабочий код будет примерно таким:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter1 = new Counter();

        Counter counter2 = new Counter();
        Counter counter3 = new Counter();
        Counter counter4 = new Counter();

        counter1.start();
        counter2.start();
        counter3.start();
        counter4.start();

        counter1.join();
        counter2.join();
        counter3.join();
        counter4.join();


        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("значение " + i + "= " + values[i]);
        }
    }

    public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static int[] values = new int[105];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 105; i++) {
            values[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count.get();
    }

    public static class Counter extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                synchronized (values) {
                    incrementCount();
                    values[getCount()]++;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } while (getCount() < 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если каждый поток увеличивает значения массива на 1, почему значения равны 1 а не 4?

Comment: @Gennadyi потому, что каждый поток увеличивает значение counter, которое видят все остальные потоки. Если нужно, чтоб значения были равны 4, то нужно переменную count делать локальной для класса Counter

Comment: @Roman Danilov Здесь синхронизация происходит по объекту. То, о чем пишете Вы, проявилось бы в случае synchronized(Counter.class) или synchronized(this.getClass()). (Код запускал, вроде подтверждается)

Comment: @ГригорийСтепанов, да, согласен, проглядел, что класс статический, а не метод